# How to implement User roles in nodejs passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

How to implement role based authorization / access control in nodejs using expressjs and passport also how to design Role Middleware perfectly ?

I have two types of login **Admin** and **User**

which is best, creating two model and router in the name of admin and user?

1.Checking user `isAdmin` or not

2.

```
// To authtenticate the User by JWT Startegy
module.exports = (userType, passport) => {
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
        if (userType == 'admin') {
            Admin.getAdminById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, user) => {
                if (err) return done(err, false);
                if (user) return done(null, user);
                return done(null, false);
            });
        }
        if (userType == 'users') {
            User.getUserById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, user) => {
                if (err) return done(err, false);
                if (user) return done(null, user);
                return done(null, false);
            });
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to have 2 places to get user data?

Have users and assign roles to them.

The easiest access control system is: guest, logged in, admin.

So in table `users` add a `role` column with values: user, admin.

And now you write middlewares:

```js
const isLogged = function (req, res, next) {
   if (req.user)
     return next ();
   res.send ('unauth')
}
const isAdmin = function (req, res, next) {
   if (req.user.role == 'admin')
     return next ();
   res.send ('only admin')
}
```

And usage:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{})
app.get('/profile',isLogged, (req, res)=>{})
app.get('/admin',isLogged, isAdmin, (req, res)=>{})
```

For more advanced needs try find some ACL modules